# Ruby replacing only the first occurrence of multiple regexes passed as a hash

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have a paragraph of text and want to only Ruby `sub` the first regex match of the word. This would be fine if I only had to match one string, but I'm passing multiple regexes into my sub:

```
regex = Regexp.new(["Lebron James", "Chris Paul"].join("|"))
names_hash = {"Lebron James" => "**Lebron James**", "Chris Paul" => "**Chris Paul**"}

str = "of the best players left in the playoffs, Lebron James is the most experienced player left in the field and probably in all of the league. Chris Paul has played in many playoff games but has never been to a conference final. Lebron James on the other hand, has been to seven straight NBA finals."
```

If I run `str.gsub(regex, names_hash)`, all instances of Lebron James and Chris Paul get replaced to:

> "of the best players left in the playoffs, **Lebron James** is the most
>   experienced player left in the field and probably in all of the
>   league. **Chris Paul** has played in many playoff games but has never
>   been to a conference final. **Lebron James** on the other hand, has been
>   to seven straight NBA finals."

And if I run `str.sub(regex, names_hash)` (sub instead of gsub), I get only the first occurrence of Lebron James, but not Chris Paul:

> "of the best players left in the playoffs, **Lebron James** is the most
>   experienced player left in the field and probably in all of the
>   league. Chris Paul has played in many playoff games but has never been
>   to a conference final. Lebron James on the other hand, has been to
>   seven straight NBA finals."

My question:

How do I set up what I have so that I can replace both the first instance of Lebron James and Chris Paul, but not the second reference of Lebron James? My expected result:

> "of the best players left in the playoffs, **Lebron James** is the most
>   experienced player left in the field and probably in all of the
>   league. **Chris Paul** has played in many playoff games but has never been
>   to a conference final. Lebron James on the other hand, has been to
>   seven straight NBA finals."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
regex = Regexp.new(["Lebron James", "Chris Paul"].join("|"))
names_hash = {"Lebron James" => "**Lebron James**", "Chris Paul" => "**Chris Paul**"}
str = "of the best players left in the playoffs, Lebron James is the most experienced player left in the field and probably in all of the league. Chris Paul has played in many playoff games but has never been to a conference final. Lebron James on the other hand, has been to seven straight NBA finals."


str.gsub(regex) { |name| names_hash.delete(name) || name }
```

This will read from the `names_hash` only for the first replacement; after that, the `gsub` will "default" to making no alteration.

Note that this approach mutates the original `names_hash` - so you may need to `dup` it beforehand if the variable is needed later on.

Comment: Exquisitely! Like.

Comment: Thanks this answers it perfectly, simple and easy to understand. However a quick extension on the original question, how could `str.gsub(regex) { |name| names_hash.delete(name) || name }` be written to support multiple `str`s? If I pass another string to the gsub, it won't replace anything in the second string.

Comment: @FrankBi That's because the `names_hash` variable loses it's key/value pair after a match. Like the answer stated: "Note that this approach mutates the original names_hash - so you may need to dup it beforehand if the variable is needed later on." This means you'll have to duplicate the hash beforehand. Something like this will do: `names_hash.dup.yield_self { |names_hash| str.gsub(regex) { |name| names_hash.delete(name) || name } }` (*Object#yield_self* is introduced in Ruby 2.5.0). Alternatively you can just create a new variable beforehand and use that instead.

Comment: @JohanWentholt `Object#tap` was introduced in Ruby 1.0 and it works pretty fine here.

Comment: @mudasobwa That doesn't return the string as result.

Comment: @JohanWentholt sure it does (with `break`): `names_hash.dup.tap { |names_hash| break str.gsub(regex) { |name| names_hash.delete(name) || name } }`.

Comment: @mudasobwa You got me there. I'll often forget you can jump out of blocks with `break`.

Comment: Good one, Tom!. I would like to see word breaks (`\b`) in the regex, however, to avoid matching, for example, "Chris Pauly". This applies to all answers, of course.

Comment: Sure @CarySwoveland, I agree there are some edge cases that the regex does not account for - but I considered that beyond the scope of the question :) For example, the simple `.join("|")` approach above would not escape any special characters (use `Regexp.escape` if needed), or maybe you'll also need to highlight abbreviations like "L James"... Who knows! But given the input/output provided, this is sufficient.

Comment: You could alternative write `regex.default_proc = ->(_,k) { k }` and then remove `|| name` from the block.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to call `sub` separately for each name in sequence.

Alternatively, you can use the block form of `gsub` to keep track of which names you've already highlighted:

```
names_seen = []
regex = Regexp.union(["Lebron James", "Chris Paul"])

str = ..
str.gsub(regex) do |name|
  if names_seen.include?(name)
    name # not the first; replace with itself
  else
    names_seen << name # remember
    "**#{name}**" # or use `names_hash[name]` if needed
  end
end
```

Comment: Making `names_seen` a Hash or Set would be slightly more efficient, but with a short list, it doesn't really matter, so Array is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Although [Tom Lords answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50493275/3982562) is good, I want to show you a different way of solving your issue. My solution involves calling [*String#sub*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-sub) as many times as you have names.

```
str = 'of the best players left in the playoffs, Lebron James is the most experienced player left in the field and probably in all of the league. Chris Paul has played in many playoff games but has never been to a conference final. Lebron James on the other hand, has been to seven straight NBA finals.'
names = ['Lebron James', 'Chris Paul']
```

**original answer**

```
replacements = names.map { |name| "**#{name}**" }
replacements = names.zip(replacements)

replacements.inject(str) { |str, args| str.sub(*args) }
```

As [mudasobwa pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492954/ruby-replacing-only-the-first-occurrence-of-multiple-regexes-passed-as-a-hash/50494429#comment88002073_50494429), the *#map* / *#zip* might be overkill. You could just run the following instead:

```
names.inject(str) { |str, name| str.sub(name, "**#{name}**") }
```

**returns**

> "of the best players left in the playoffs, **Lebron James** is the most experienced player left in the field and probably in all of the league. **Chris Paul** has played in many playoff games but has never been to a conference final. Lebron James on the other hand, has been to seven straight NBA finals."

**references**

- [*Array#map*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map)
- [*Array#zip*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-zip)
- [*Enumerable#inject*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Comment: Neat. The `map`/`zip` seems to be an overkill here, since one might just `names.inject(str) { |str, name| str.sub(name, "**#{name}**") }`.